# Pi3 Lirc problem

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, pi-3, lirc

I had my Raspberry Pi 2 setup with lirc, fully working with the keys that I needed.
But when i upgraded to Pi 3, using the same GPIO pins, configuration and remote control, I can`t get irrecord to recognize any of the keys that I press, and irw does not recognize them either.

When i check the signals with

```
mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
```

I get a never-ending stream of random signals.

I'm running with the latest release and updates of raspbian jessie.
Is there a problem with my Raspberry pi 3 or something that`s different?

Comment: An error introduced by the  change in wiring is more likely to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have the problem where after typing `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` and then pointing controller to ir receiver and pressing buttons nothing shows up at all. On the receiver it looks all fine as the light is blinking once I press the buttons, everything is wired up correctly as well..